# remove characters and duplicates from csv file and write to new file

Tags: python

I'm reading from a csv file that looks like this:

```
[152.60115606936415][152.60115606936415, 13181.818181818182][152.60115606936415, 13181.818181818182, 1375055.330634278][152.60115606936415, 13181.818181818182, 1375055.330634278, 89.06882591093118]
```

what I want to do is to remove the characters ([,] and spaces to a new line) and write it into my new txt fil

```
import csv
to_file =open("t_put.txt","w")
with open("t_put_val.20181026052328.csv", "r") as f:
   for row in (list(csv.reader(f))):
   value2= (" ".join(row)[1:-1]) #remove 3 first and last elements
   value = value2.replace("  ","\n")# replace spaces with newline
   value3 = value.replace("]["," ") # replace ][
   value4 = value3.replace(" ","\n")
   print(value4)
  # st = str(s)
   to_file.write(value4)#write to file
to_file.close()
```

With this code I am able to remove the characters, but still duplicates are showing up. I was thinking of putting using the set() method , but its not working as intended or just print out the four last digits, but might not work for larger data set

Comment: Can you show your current result, to reproduce the answer..

Comment: my current result when running the code: 573956.3182527301
573956.3182527301
2090614221.115538                                                                                     as you see it just prints everything out, it does not remove duplicates
573956.3182527301
2090614221.115538
92.26467847157502
573956.3182527301
2090614221.115538
92.26467847157502
63.127690100430414

Comment: there are enough answers in place to consider where you can upvote and accept the one which seems to fit so as to clear from the un-answered queue.

Comment: updated the answer as per you defined in the comment, hope that will help.

Comment: yes, thank you for your time

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21643/405735

Comment: @pygo You literally looked at my answer and copied my method in your edit. As long as people are helped and the OP gets the answer, I don't mind, but it's just not a respectful practice to continue.

Comment: @leeym, Initially OP asked about set() method which i are proposed in the answer when later he told about order which is why i took orderdict as a module and not your answer at all if you see my answer that do not match to your , while talking about module which is free to be used by anyone you cant say your methos until the logic is your , Moreover i told OP to look for your solution and even upvoted your answer... i'm afraid about being respectful practice here!

Answer (score 1):

By splitting by ']', you can group each of the lists that reside inside the csv.

```
# Open up the csv file
with open("t_put_val.20181026052328.csv", "r") as f_h:
    rows = [row.lstrip('[').split(", ")
            # For each line in the file (there's just one)
            for line in f_h.readlines()
            # Dont' want a blank line
            if not len(line) == 0
            # Split the line by trailing ']'s
            for row in line.split(']')
            # Don't want the last blank list
            if not len(row) == 0
            ]

# Print out all unique values
unique_values = set(item for row in rows for item in row)
[print(value) for value in unique_values];

# Output
with open("t_put.txt", 'w') as f_h:
    f_h.writelines('%s\n' % ', '.join(row) for row in rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `set` is an unordered data structure.

Better way to convert your String output to list object and then use python `set()` method which is mean for this:

```
>>> my_int = [152.60115606936415, 13181.818181818182, 152.60115606936415, 13181.818181818182, 1375055.330634278, 152.60115606936415]
```

You can use set directly to list in order to get the duplicate removed..

```
>>> set(my_int)
{152.60115606936415, 13181.818181818182, 1375055.330634278}
```

However, if you Don't wish to choose above and rather want list output then can opt like below...

```
>>> list(set(my_int))
[152.60115606936415, 13181.818181818182, 1375055.330634278]
```

## Using the `collections.OrderedDict` ..

As per the conversation required output should be in ordered form hence using the `OrderedDict` to preserve the order of the dataset.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
to_file =open("ttv","w")
with open("tt", "r") as f:
    for row in (list(csv.reader(f))):
         value2= (" ".join(row)[1:-1]) #remove 3 first and last elements
         value = value2.replace("  ","\n")# replace spaces with newline
         value3 = value.replace("]["," ") # replace ][
         value4 = value3.replace(" ","\n")
         value4 = OrderedDict.fromkeys(value4.split())
         #value4 = sorted(set(value4.split()))
         for line in value4:
             line = line.split(',')
             for lines in line:
                 new_val = lines
                 print(new_val)
                 to_file.write(new_val + '\n')#write to file
to_file.close()
```

**result:**

```
152.60115606936415
13181.818181818182
1375055.330634278
89.06882591093118
```

Comment: I see the output is in the wrong order, is it simply just to sort it?

Comment: but 152.60115606936415 is read first from the file but appears almost last: 
152.60115606936415
13181.818181818182
1375055.330634278
89.06882591093118   im using this result to draw a graph

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct in assuming that you just want to write every unique value to a new line in your output file, this will also preserve the original order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('t_put_val.20181026052328.csv', 'r') as infile, open('t_put.txt', 'w') as outfile:
data = infile.read()
# List of characters to replace
to_replace = ['[', ']', ' ']
for char in to_replace:
    if char in data:
        data = data.replace(char, '')
unique_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data.split(',')))
for i in unique_list:
    outfile.write(i + '\n')
```

Yields this in the txt file:

```
152.60115606936415
13181.818181818182
1375055.330634278
89.06882591093118
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your script in a way given below combined with linux command line as follows:
If you compile your script the answer would be:

```
./yourscript.py

152.60115606936415
152.60115606936415
13181.818181818182
152.60115606936415
13181.818181818182
1375055.330634278
152.60115606936415
13181.818181818182
1375055.330634278
89.06882591093118
```

But if you use [pipes](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/01/23/piping-in-linux-how-to-use-pipes-in-shell/) in shell and write your output to a file then duplicates can be removed easily as follows:

```
./yourscript.py |sort|uniq > yourresultfile
```

If you see the results of your file it will look as

```
cat yourresultfile
13181.818181818182
1375055.330634278
152.60115606936415
89.06882591093118
```

In this way you can remove duplicates from your file.

So if you want pythonic way for doing this then below is rather silly way of achieving your desired output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as myfile:
     data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

str1= data.replace('[','')
str2= str1.replace(']',',')
list1=str2.split(',')
list2=list(set(k))
list3=[x.strip() for x in list2 if x.strip()]
list4=[float(i) for i in list3]
with open('out_put_file.txt','w') as f:
     f.write(json.dumps(list4))
```

The file  **out_put_file.txt** contains output as follows:

```
[13181.818181818182, 1375055.330634278, 89.06882591093118, 152.60115606936415]
```

Comment: OP  is looking for  a way in Python not Linux way, so this irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, this works, but I'm looking for a way in python within my code. Any way to do that command in python?

Comment: Check the latest solution provided by me.